# how to open a text file with an editor on append mode

Tags: linux, text-editor

If I do this:

```
touch newfile.txt
sudo chattr +a newfile.txt
```

I can then add content to that file using:

```
echo "Hello world" >> newfile.txt
```

Is there away I can do the above with a text editor such as vim, gedit, etc?
Note that opening the this file the normal way with text editors will fail when trying to save.

Comment: Are you trying to open the file such that you can only add text to the end and the rest is not editable ?

Comment: What kind of file-system is that? Do You have root access to it? There is append_only flag at some FileSystems, like XFS, ext2, ext3.

What about just removing `a` attribute before editing? And changing it back after that.

Comment: Why does the save fail? Permission issues?

Comment: @Varad, the save fail because of the append-only attribute that was set on the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply open a plain vim session and then save your text with

```
:w >> newfile.txt
```